# Clamav TCP 3310 setup Debian

Tags: debian, clamav

I've run into this problem which is weird. I'm using Debian jessie and I have setup clamav to listen also on port 3310 with the `TCPSocket 3310` option.

After saving the changes to the config file I restart the daemon with `service clamav-daemon restart` and check if its listening on port 3310 with `lsof -i tcp:3310` and it is not.

If I run the daemon manually with `clamd --config=/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` the everything works perfectly. I have tried to check if there is a `/etc/defaults/clam` script but there is none. Where can I set the preferences for the startup script to use the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon` and make your Configuration over this cli-interface.

`lsof -i tcp:3310
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd    1   root   28u  IPv6 356619      0t0  TCP *:3310 (LISTEN)
clamd   2503 clamav    3u  IPv6 356619      0t0  TCP *:3310 (LISTEN)`